# Where can I obtain research reports

Tags: investing, stock-analysis, stock-valuation, research

As EU citizen interested in investing in US stocks, I'm interested in reading some local research about US companies from US banks/brokers. Where can I find such research reports? Do I have to pay or have an account with the said brokers to get access to their research ?

EDIT: I am also interested in paid services. For example, I heard that such reports can be found on Refinitiv Eikonal, but it is not clear which firms publish there or whether they publish only a part of their research reports (i.e. do they undertake to publish all their research on that platform?)

EDIT 2 : I am also interested in **paid** research

EDIT 3 : I see this question has been closed as off-topic, the motivation being that you apparently look for questions that are widely relevant for a long time. But let's take a minute to reflect : **money matters change fast**! Things won't be the same in 10 years, just like 10 years ago regulations/taxes etc. were different. This is not mathematics; finance is a social phenomenon.
**"The times change, and we change with them."**

Answer (score 2):

If you're not interested in paying a research firm, you're left with public sources of data. Depending on the specific factors you care about, that could come from one of a number of sources:

1. [The Securities and Exchange Commission](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) - The agency responsible for regulating and enforcing against publicly traded companies. These companies must make regular filings showing their balance sheets, earnings statements, corporate policies, and a slew of other information - on the regular. This is where most people who want information about specific companies will go.
2. News media - For a lot of topics that aren't about the money, including things like lawsuits, accusations of misconduct, and other things, you can search news outlets for that company's name, the names of its officers, etc. This isn't research per se, and you should always consider the sources cited before you decide it's good information - but it is free, and most journalists do at least a bit of homework before they publish.
3. [PACER and other resources](https://pacer.uscourts.gov/) - For things like lawsuits past and present (at least as far back as records have been digitized), there are tools like PACER for the Federal court system, and most states have similar systems.  If you can get to a law library you can also use their Lexis access (or similar tools)
4. Finally, the corporations themselves will frequently commission studies and internal reviews and make these public as a matter of transparency.  Definitely consider the source here, but again if you're not paying for research you're at the mercy of either raw data or parties who are giving you information that serves their interests for you to have.

Comment: I am also interested in paid-for research, documents that paint a different picture, containing price targets, estimated, comments about the business etc. Which firms could provide such paid-for research (without opening an account with them) ?

Comment: Paid-for financial research is going to be pretty well paywalled. You might find retail products available for a fee, but it's highly likely that any copies of these you can acquire for free are violating a user agreement somewhere.

Comment: I don't see a problem with them being paywalled. I can pay, but the question is : which firms are willing to sell to retail investors?

Comment: You should change your question then. You say: **"EDIT: I am not also interested in paid services."**